# CSOM, GroupBy, specific ViewFields and system fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, caml-query

From my SP library, I would need to retrieve a list of meetingID grouped by MeetingID.
I tried several attempts with CAML but it didn't work:

```
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                    query.ViewXml = @"<View>  
                                        <Query>
                                            <Where>        
                                            <And>                                        
                                                <And>
                                                    <Eq>
                                                        <FieldRef Name='FSObjType'/> 
                                                        <Value Type='Counter'>0</Value>
                                                    </Eq>
                                                    <Geq>
                                                        <FieldRef Name='Modified'/>
                                                        <Value IncludeTimeValue = 'TRUE' Type = 'DateTime'>2016-01-01T15:55:52Z</Value>           
                                                    </Geq>  
                                                </And>
                                                <IsNotNull>
                                                    <FieldRef Name='Title' />                                              
                                                </IsNotNull>
                                            </And>
                                        </Where>                                       
                                        <GroupBy Collapse='True'>
                                            <FieldRef Name='MeetingID' />
                                        </GroupBy>                                        
                                        <OrderBy>
                                            <FieldRef Name='DocID' />                                       
                                        </OrderBy>
                                    </Query> 
                                    <ViewFields>
                                        <FieldRef Name='MeetingID'/>
                                    </ViewFields> 
                                </View>";

                    ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
                    cc.Load(items, o => o.Include(p => p["MeetingID"]));
                    cc.ExecuteQuery();
```

Considering that the CAML is returning the MeetingID and plenty of system fields, I had to use the `Include` syntax. However,on my 1500 items in SP, none of them have been grouped (I should have only 50 unique MeetingID). Again probably related to the system fields which prevent the grouping to occur...

I also tried:

```
cc.Load(items, o => o.Include(p => p["MeetingID"]).GroupBy(g=>g["MeetingID"]));
```

But this one return an error...

I also tried to see if a property similar to `ViewFieldsOnly` exist in CSOM but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the code snippet and actually, the CAML Query have done groupby as expected:

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://zheguo.sharepoint.com/sites/dev"))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                List targetList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("doc3");
                clientContext.Load(targetList);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                query.ViewXml = @"<View>  
                                        <Query>
                                            <Where>        
                                            <And>                                        
                                                <And>
                                                    <Eq>
                                                        <FieldRef Name='FSObjType'/> 
                                                        <Value Type='Counter'>0</Value>
                                                    </Eq>
                                                    <Geq>
                                                        <FieldRef Name='Modified'/>
                                                        <Value IncludeTimeValue = 'TRUE' Type = 'DateTime'>2016-01-01T15:55:52Z</Value>           
                                                    </Geq>  
                                                </And>
                                                <IsNotNull>
                                                    <FieldRef Name='Title' />                                              
                                                </IsNotNull>
                                            </And>
                                        </Where>                                       
                                        <GroupBy Collapse='True'>
                                            <FieldRef Name='MeetingID' />
                                        </GroupBy>                                        
                                    </Query> 
                                    <ViewFields>
                                        <FieldRef Name='MeetingID'/>
                                        <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
                                        <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                                    </ViewFields> 
                                </View>";

                ListItemCollection items = targetList.GetItems(query);
                clientContext.Load(items, o => o.Include(p => p["MeetingID"], p=>p["ID"],p=>p["Title"] ) );
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item["MeetingID"]);
                    Console.WriteLine(item["Title"]);
                }


            }
```

Here is the sample data in my library for a test:

[image]

There are 2 unique MeetingID- "Meeting001" "Meeting002", you can see the result from Console.WriteLine, the same MeetingID item will be grouped together:
[image]